# Upload a photo on click/submit button

Tags: jquery, forms, api, onclick, submit

how can I get jQuery to execute **on click** instead of just when user chooses a file? I tried *onclick* and *submit* on line 2 instead of change, to no avail:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
      $('input[type=file]').on("change", function() {
            var $files = $(this).get(0).files;
            $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
                  console.log(response[1].link);
```

```html
<form>
  <input class="imgur" type="file" accept="image/*" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: on submit ,form is submited/posted, so you have to submit the form .

Comment: Using `submit` won't work if you're attaching it to the *file* element; use it on the `form` instead: `$("form").submit(function() { /* handle submit */  })`